# Requesting HealthKit Access via Apple Watch only?

Tags: ios, apple-watch, healthkit

Is it still the case that a user cannot grant HealthKit access on the watch alone even though Watch Series 3 now can be completely untethered via LTE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the user must still grant HealthKit access to WatchKit apps on watchOS 4 using the phone.